# When people saying 'with high probability', are there two possible interpretations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

I've seen two meaning of 'with high probability' in the literature, and I think they are different. I am not sure whether I miss understood them. Here are they:

(1) In mathematics, an event that occurs with high probability (often shortened to w.h.p. or WHP) is one whose probability depends on a certain number n and goes to 1 as n goes to infinity, i.e. the probability of the event occurring can be made as close to 1 as desired by making n big enough. (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_high_probability)) For example [here](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Erezaul/Fall-2017/CSE548/CSE548-lecture-11.pdf) An event Π is said to occur with high probability if $P(Π)\geq 1-\frac{c}{n^\alpha}$.

(2) In the context of concentration, if we have $P(X\geq a+t)\leq \exp(-t^2)$, then we say $X<a$ with high probability. This means that the larger the deviation from what we expected ($X<a$), the smaller the probability is. For example, [theorem 3.1.1](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf). proved $P\{\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}\geq t\}\leq 2\exp(-\frac{ct^2}{K4})$, and call it 'with high probability $X$ takes values very close to the sphere of radius $\sqrt{n}$'. Also, I noticed that in some concentration bound, it can depend on $n$ as well.

From my understanding, the first one is saying the probability is bounded by a function of $n$, while the second one is bounded by a function of deviation, which is commonly addressed topic in the context of concentration.

I am not sure whether 'with high probability' is a vague word, and its definition depends on the context, or I misunderstood something.

Could someone help to clarify more? Thanks in advance for any comment, answer.

Comment: If an event is not sure but has probability $1$ , we say it occurs almost surely. What "high" means depends on the context. In some cases , $p=0.8$ is already consiederd to be "high".

Comment: I don't think the phrase "high probability" has a mathematical meaning. In statistics (and science) it's usually compared against the null hypothesis and the probability that the null hypothesis predicts the results, which is typically a 5-10% chance. So if an experiment "passes" this test, that there's only a 5-10% chance random results could explain it, then we say it's "highly probably"--although what we're actually saying is there's a 90-95% chance we're correct.

Comment: ...and to add to that, that's why repeatability is so important in science. If I do an experiment with 90-95% accuracy, someone else should _also_ be able to repeat that experiment with the same (or similar) results--if they don't then my experiment is flawed. The more it's repeated with that same 90-95% threshold, the more accurate it becomes.

Comment: It's really just some convention by the author. Tao makes this notion exact in "Topics in Random Matrix Theory."